# How to export directX in py script

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to make a script to export all my objects to individual .x files. However I don't know the operators for directX. Please tell me how I can fix this code so that it exports the directX files.

`bpy.ops.export_scene.x(filepath=str(path + ob.name + '.x'),check_existing=True)`

This worked for .obj files.

Comment: remove the `,check_existing=True`

Comment: Tried that its not the problem.

Comment: what console output do you see ?

Comment: None? How do I see the output console, this is my first time writing script in python for blender.

Comment: in blender go to Window->Toggle_system_console you'll a cmd console (don't close it ) read the output in most case it will be very helpful

Comment: Wow thanks, that might be a bit helpful for like everything that I'm about to do :D

Comment: That really helped XD, I was trying to create a folder I already created earlier on in the script, now I have my script working thanks to you :D

Comment: glad to help, but you have to write an answer (steps and some script ) in here (and accept it ) so this can be more useful to others facing the same problem